# Field remember settings

Tags: entities, users

Let's say we have a content with these fields:

- Title
- Category
- Price
- Mobile
- Skype
- City
- E-mail

A checkbox for "Remember my settings" that will remember these fields:

- Mobile
- Skype
- City
- E-mail

When user is registered in profile edit will have an option to change (I guess this will be able to achieve with Profile2):

- Mobile
- Skype
- City
- E-mail

After changing these details, the next new content form will have a checkbox for "Use my settings" to use the settings from the profile form details. Is it possible to do this with a module or hook in Drupal 7?

I'm not asking for someone to explain me the details (even it's very welcomed), but I'm asking if it's possible, what module or hook should I use? I hope this doesn't sounds too broad.

Comment: Why not to just pull these values from user's profile on node display? Do you *require* them to be editable on node edit too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Remember values](https://drupal.org/project/remember_values)

> This module enables Drupal to remember entered values from selected
>   fields upon new node submission, stores them in the database and then
>   pre-fills appropriate fields on the next node-add form. This is useful
>   when a user needs to enter many nodes at a time and some of the
>   fields' values are repeating.

Comment: Bala, thank you very much for the link of this module. It does remember specific fields, it stores on the database for every single user, however it doesn't have a checkbox on creating node form to remember or NOT to remember the settings.

Comment: @user2519032 have you checked this demo http://remember.senberniai.com/ user name and password will appear in popup.

Comment: After loged in go to this url http://remember.senberniai.com/admin/content/node-type/product you can see the check box options

Comment: Yes, I've checked that link, but I meant to say checkbox as a field. Let's say when the user enters the /node/add/custom-type and in the form to have a checkbox for remembering the settings and than in the next new content the marked fields from admin/structure/types/manage/custom-type will be remembered.

Comment: this will auto fill the fields, once you checked the remember fields under content type edit. -

Comment: I've already checked the fields that will support this remember function in content type edit, but let's say the website has a lot of users and some of them doesn't like this function, so in create node form it should be visible checkbox to use or not to use this function.